# Combining results from two tables into a unified table without common data

Tags: sql, join, insert, create-table

I've read a bunch of examples on merging tables but most people have a joinable content. I do not have any data that can be joined upon except by using a FULL JOIN which leaves me multiple columns with the same name and NULLs where there is no data in the corresponding query.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpBus
(
id varchar(50),
partnumber varchar(400),
attributecname nvarchar(255),
attributevalue nvarchar(1700),
assetfilename varchar(85),
orderby varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpBus1
(
id varchar(50),
name varchar(500),
url varchar(2550),
assetfilename varchar(850),
orderby varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpBus2
(
partnumber varchar(400),
attributecname varchar(255),
attributevale varchar(1700),
orderby varchar(10),
assetfilename varchar(850),
name varchar(500),
url varchar(2550)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpBus exec getSectionNewData 5665976;

INSERT INTO #tmpBus1 exec getSectionFeaturedData 5665976;

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #tmpBus tb
FULL JOIN #tmpBus1 tb1
ON tb.partnumber=tb1.name

DROP TABLE #tmpBus
DROP TABLE #tmpBus1
DROP TABLE #tmpBus2
```

My  goal is to get the data from the 2 temp tables (#tmpBus & #tmpBus1) I've created into one unified table (#tmpBus2).  I tried every type of join and group by method I can think of. Here is a screenshot of the output of the above code.  Notice the NULLs.  I am trying to get a flat table into #tmpBus2 with the corresponding values from each table.  So, the id,assetfilename and orderby fields would be unified instead of 2 separate columns and the ability to order by the orderby column.

[image]

Any help getting me headed in the right direction would be super helpful.

Comment: Are you after every combination of items from the source tables?  If so go for a cross join (no on statement required).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, I've already tried the cross join and the output is the same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple UNION join

```
SELECT id, partnernumber, attributecname, attributevalue, assetfilename, orderby, NULL AS url
FROM #tmpBus tb
UNION
SELECT id, name, NULL, NULL, assetfilename, orderby, url
FROM #tmpBus1 tb1
ORDER BY orderby
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried a UNION prior to this post but not in the manner you have. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to consolidate multiple columns into single ones you may want to try this:

```
SELECT 
--isnull(tb.id, tb1.id)                         Id
  isnull(tb.partnumber, tb1.name)               PartNumber
, tb.attributecname                             AttributeCName
, tb.attributevalue                             AttributeValue
, isnull(tb.orderby, tb1.orderby)               OrderBy
, isnull(tb.assetfilename, tb1.assetfilename)   AssetFilename
, isnull(tb1.name, tb.partnumber)               Name
, tb1.url                                       URL
FROM #tmpBus tb
FULL JOIN #tmpBus1 tb1
ON tb.partnumber=tb1.name
```

Without knowing more about your data / requirements I can't help much more - if you can provide some sample input data & expected output though I (or someone here) can tweak the query to meet your needs.